# How to extract a dynamic href link from another file

Tags: javascript, html, href

How can I create a dynamic href on my web page that can read the links from another file such that every time I upload a new file with a different set of links the href path will change?

Text file contains the following records:
1 www.google.com
2 www.apple.com
3 www.ibm.com

HTML Page

```
<div class="slide" id="slide-1">
<a href="(*path of text file + 1st record*)"  target="_blank"> 
<img class="resize" src="/images/DIY00/1.jpg" alt=""/> </a></div>

<div class="slide" id="slide-2">
<a href="(*path of text file + 2nd record*)" target="_blank"> 
<img class="resize" src="/images/DIY00/2.jpg" alt=""/> </a></div>

<div class="slide" id="slide-3">
<a href="(*path of text file + 3rd record*)" target="_blank"> 
<img class="resize" src="/images/DIY00/3.jpg" alt=""/> </a></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read the links from another file"?

Comment: I want the url strings to be read from a separate file. For example, lets assume I had a plain text file called urllist.txt and in the file I had a record $1 = www.google.com. My webpage would execute <a href="$1"></a> which would translate <a href="www.google.com"></a>. Now if the change the url in the urllist.txt file to $1= www.yahoo.com, my webpage would execute  <a href="$1"></a> which would translate to<a href="www.yahoo.com"></a>. I am looking for a way to parse the url string from another file so I don't have to open and manually edit my webpage. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is it. If the first line on 1.txt is www.google.com, the hyperlink with resolve to this domain.

```
<script>
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
     document.getElementById("link1").href=this.responseText;
    }
  };

xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/1.txt", true); 
xhttp.send(xhttp); 
</script>

<a id="link1" href="#" target="_blank"></a> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what you are asking here but I think it's that you want to be able to pull continuous hrefs with updated urls?  If that is the case you should be able pass in the updated href as a new string as that is how the href element is passed in the first place.